# Recommended port for proxy server

Tags: ports, proxy-server

I'm trying to create a proxy server, and am having trouble decide on a trivial thing -- the port number on which it will listen. Is there some kind of convention on which port a proxy server should run on? Or should it just be greater than 1024?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you just pick a port and make it changeable for the user (or yourself). Simply, if it is already used on the system you run your proxy on, use a different one.

Many free proxy servers even listen (e.g. [this](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/)) to default ports, like 8080. As long as the port is not in use on your system, it does not matter, as the real port is negotiated after a connection attempt.

For your interest, a [list of registered ports](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) can be found on the IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority), which manages stuff like that. That is only a hint. I normaly use a random port like 8888 or so, even if someone somewhere already uses that.